# Laravel queues - limit number of simultaneous tasks

Tags: php, multithreading, thread-safety, queue, laravel-5

I have written a Laravel task which reads data from db, calls a shell script to process data, and that saves results to db. Tasks are queued very fast, and multiple tasks always exist in the queue. I noticed that tasks are not performed one by one, but instead couple of tasks are executed simultaneously. This is good principle, generally speaking, but it seems that shell script I call(which is btw third-party and I cannot modify it) is not thread-safe and it creates problems when called simultaneously by multiple tasks. When I am executing task function synchronously, as part of my main process, everything works smooth.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to tell Laravel queue process one task at a time, because I still want to split this job from my main processing, but also have to avoid these errors. I am on Laravel 5, using default 'sync' queue method.

Answer (score 0):

About the tasks being executed simultaneously, have you tried adding `withoutOverlapping` ?
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps

If you're using a closure call, you'd also need to add a `name`

For example:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'user_id'       => '3',
        'name'          => 'anton'
    ]);
})->everyHour()
  ->name('nyanpasu')
  ->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: well, I am calling my job like this `Queue::pushOn('tagger', new TaggerJob($idFeed));`, it is a queue job, not a laravel task being called periodically, maybe I didn't express well what I am trying to do. 
However, option you mention for preventing task overlapping is another thing I was looking for, so this answer is very helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any answer that could fit my needs and this question is in top 10 search results for "laravel limit one job", so I decided that I'll share my solution to this problem. maybe it'll help someone else.

I had jobs overlapping for an API requests which resulted in 500 error on the external server. To overcome this issue I wanted to limit the execution to one job.

The simplest solution for me was to **create another Supervisor configuration file for one specific queue** - in my case "api" - which I limited in the config to one proces with `numprocs=1` command.

After this I can dispatch all API jobs for external servers to queue "api" and they never overlap.

I don't know if it's the best approach but it fixed my problems with minimum effort.